# How to get values from xml in SQL Server 2012

Tags: sql, xml, sql-server-2012

I have table about 9000 rows and I need from every row I need to get some values and also name values from xml.

Table columns: `Eaid`, `Created`, `AttachedApplication`

XML:

```
<NamedApplication xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <mainpart>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <extras />
    </mainpart>
</NamedApplication>
```

I can't get results in table. Name and surname is resulted as NULL

Comment: This is not valid XML - the `<NamedApplication>` node isn't closed. Is the closing tag just missing here? Also: is this XML contained in a column of your table - if so: **which** column?? And what do you want to extract from it??

Comment: Yes, i missed closing. XML is in "AttachedApplication" column in database. I need to get firstname and surname

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
SELECT
    EAId,
    FirstName = xc.value('(firstname)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    Surname = xc.value('(surname)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    dbo.YourTableName
CROSS APPLY
    AttachedApplication.nodes('/NamedApplication/mainpart') AS XT(XC)
```

This will "enumerate" over your table, returning the `EAID` column, and it will "reach into" the XML and grab the `<firstname>` and `<surname>` nodes from within that XML and expose them as separate columns in the output.

**UPDATE:** if you run this example which uses a table variable - does it work and return values??

```
DECLARE @Table TABLE (Eaid INT, Created DATE, AttachedApplication XML)

INSERT INTO @Table (Eaid, Created, AttachedApplication)
VALUES (1, GETDATE(),
    '<NamedApplication xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <mainpart>
        <firstname>John</firstname>
        <surname>Smith</surname>
        <extras />
    </mainpart>
</NamedApplication>')

SELECT
    EAId,
    FirstName = xc.value('(firstname)[1]', 'varchar(100)'),
    Surname = xc.value('(surname)[1]', 'varchar(100)')
FROM
    @Table
CROSS APPLY
    AttachedApplication.nodes('/NamedApplication/mainpart') AS XT(XC)
```

Comment: This unfortunately brings 0 results

Comment: @Leppalintu: then you either have no data in the table, or the XML in your column looks differently than what you're showing .....

Comment: @marc_s Isn't that due to the namespace declaration?

Comment: @TT.: no - the namespace defines a **prefix** (`xs:`), but that prefix is not used anywhere - so that namespace is basically useless. Also see my update with the runnable example - I **do get** the output expected, without paying attention to that namespace